# Using a magic IP to reach unknown target through VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, routes, kernel, bridge

I've got a strange problem related to bridging in the linux kernel.
The setup looks as follows:

[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XpJw.png).

I would like to send a packet from an userspace process of the OpenWRT router through the vpn tunnel (layer 2-tunnel) to the "Linux box". The VPN interface of the Linux box obtains its IP by the DHCP-Server of the remote network (DSL-Router). Because the address of VPNs0 (Server site) isn't known to the OpenWRT router (and can change as well as it is obtaines by DHCP) a magicIP (10.10.10.10) is used to contact the Linux box through the tunnel. There are also special devices behind eth0 of the OpenWRT-Router that use this magicIP to contact the linux box through the tunnel.

To archive this I added a static route containing the magicIP and its interface as well as a static arp table entry that specifies the interface that should be used for sending packets to this magicIP. Also this magic IP isn't actually set on any of linux box's interfaces. However all packets containing this magicIP that are received on VPNs0 (server site) are rewritten to the interfaces actual current ip-address by iptables. I know this setup is a bit hacky but it worked in the past for devices that were behind the OpenWRT router. Now I want to use the same functionality on the OpenWRT router itself but strange things happen:

If I do a ping to the magicIP from the OpenWRT router to the linux box the route is resolved according to the routing table. ARP lookup works after that as it has been provided statically. So the ping request packets are entering the br-lan interface with the correct destination mac address (VPNs0's MAC). The fdb table of the bridge associates this mac-address with the correct interface (VPN0) and send the packet(s) over the tunnel. Of cause the replay doesn't work but thats no problem as long as the packets go through.
However as soon as I use any userspace process to the same magicIP, all these packets exit on eth1. According to the fdb this can't happen as the associated interface is still VPN0.
There are no iptable or ebtable rules set that might interfere the default behavior of the switching of the bridge.

Does anybody have an idea where this might come from?